# Laravel query - Join and GroupBy

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm using laravel and I'm trying to select some stuff from the table..

```
$cars= DB::table('cars')
        ->leftJoin('types', 'cars.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
        ->groupBy('types.id')->get();
```

Basically I want 'cars' grouped in subarrays of the same "types".. but it ends up merging all group entries into only one of each car.

How can I make this query?

Comment: Does `leftJoin` is correct in this meaning? I'd say you need to use `rightJoin` to get all types and only those cars which correspond to `typeid`.

Comment: I also want to return cars of type 'null'

Comment: What exactly do you mean by subarrays?

Comment: I want an object with subobjects of different types. I can get this by doing: $cars= \App\Cars::where('active', 1)->get()->groupBy('type_id') .. but it does not join tables and I can't get type attributes such as type.title for example

Comment: @raphadko if you use Eloquent: Relationships then $cars= \App\Cars::where('active', 1)->get()->groupBy('type_id')  will work and you can even get type attributes. just need to define relationship in Models

Comment: relationship is there but it won't get the attributes of the external table... instead I'd have to make an extra database call to get the attribute using the relationship method

Comment: @raphadko can you please share your models relationship code here. it would help to catch the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If it happens that type is what you want and is merged in the return set of the $car, 
you may even remove groupBy like so

```
  $cars= DB::table('cars')
          ->leftJoin('types', 'cars.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
          ->get();
```

and then group result set  with groupBy() like so

```
   $cars->groupBy('type');
```

Remember this is possible since the result set is some sort of collection.
Thus the final code will look like this

```
   $cars= DB::table('cars')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'cars.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
      ->get();

    return $cars->groupBy('type');
```